# resolve a statement in Python in order to restart the procedure when an error occurs

Tags: python, optimization, restart

I wrote this statement in Python (for convert the program in an executable) in order to load all text files in a folder (**.txt)* or a single text file, check if the data format is correct (`get_parse` and `check_header`) and process the data. If the data format is not correct the program ask to restart (`doit = raw_input("Continue (Y/N)?[Y]: "`) . In the first case (*.txt) when the data format is not correct (delimiter '.' and presence of Header in the first line) the program reports the error and restart (if Y is press) from `INPUT = raw_input("Input (*.txt): ")`. In the second case (load a single text file) if the data format is not correct the program closes.

I wish to give also for the single load text file choose the possibility to the user to restart the program from `INPUT = raw_input("Input (*.txt): )`

```
while True:
    INPUT = raw_input("Input (*.txt): ")
    if os.path.split(INPUT)[1] == "*.txt":
        file_list = glob.glob(os.path.join(os.path.split(INPUT)[0], '*.txt'))
        for file in file_list:
            file_head, file_tail = os.path.split(file)
            file_root, file_suffix = os.path.splitext(file_tail)
            try:
                parse = get_parse(file)
            except Exception:
                print ValueError("%s has delimiter type not valid" % file_tail)
                raw_input("press any key to exit")
                print "Exiting..."
                break
            if check_header(file):
                print ValueError("%s has an Header" % file_tail)
                raw_input("press any key to exit")
                print "Exiting..."
                break
                # do other stuff
        doit = raw_input("Continue (Y/N)?[Y]: ")
        if doit == 'N'or doit == 'n':
            print "Exiting....."
            break
    else:
        try:
            parse = get_parse(INPUT)
        except Exception:
            print ValueError("Delimiter type not valid")
            raw_input("press any key to exit")
            print "Exiting..."
            break
        if check_header(INPUT):
            print ValueError("Header is not valid")
            raw_input("press any key to exit")
            print "Exiting..."
            break
        # do other stuff
        doit = raw_input("Continue (Y/N)?[Y]: ")
        if doit == 'N'or doit == 'n':
            print "Exiting....."
            break
```

in the second case, using the command prompt of windows is the text file is not correct

```
Input (*.txt): C:\test.txt
Delimiter type not valid
press any key to exit
Exiting.....

C:\Users\>
```

in the first case (*.txt)

```
Input (*.txt): C:\*.txt
Area1_1.txt has delimiter type not valid
press any key to exit
Exiting...
Continue (Y/N)?[Y]:
```

Comment: What's your question? The way I understand it, your program already does jump back to the `INPUT = ...` line in that case.

Comment: hey @TimPietzcker, not when you select only a single text file. In that case you have break and the program close

Comment: PS: @TimPietzcker, great CV compliment!!

Comment: I don't see it. You're in the `else` clause, right? So unless there are any errors, and unless you type `N` or `n` at the final prompt, the `while True:` loop continues, doesn't it?

Comment: @TimPietzcker see the update of my question. The software is go out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is still unclear, but I *think*  you want to use `continue` instead of  `break`, if your goal is to restart the loop after an error. Also, you should handle Exceptions differently:

```
<snip>
else:
    try:
        parse = get_parse(INPUT)
    except ValueError:
        print "Delimiter type not valid"
        print "Try again..."
        continue
    if check_header(INPUT):
        print "Header is not valid"
        print "Try again..."
        continue
    # do other stuff
    doit = raw_input("Continue (Y/N)?[Y]: ")
    if doit == 'N'or doit == 'n':
        print "Exiting....."
        break
```

Comment: Thanks @tim i update for the second time my question. Sorry if it's not clear and please see now the question